# Kendo Menu:How to listen the open event of menu

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

We are using the contextMenu that opens on right click of DIV.we try to listen the open event of that menu but it doesn't work.Is there any other way to do.

**here is the code**

```
<body>      
   <div style="width: 100px; height: 30px;background-color:cornsilk" id="menu"></div>     
   <div id="Ul1" style="height:40px;width:200px" />   
   <script type="text/javascript">        
     $("#menu").bind('contextmenu', function (event) {
        $("#Ul1").kendoMenu({
            orientation: "vertical",
            dataSource: [{ text: "Item1" }],
            select: function (e) {
                alert("Selected");
            },
            open:function(e){
             ---------
             ---------
            }
        });
    });       
  </script>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The open event is fired when the user hovers a menu item which has child items. It won't be fired when the menu is initialized. You can just invoke that code after creating the menu:

```
 $("#menu").bind('contextmenu', function (event) {
    $("#Ul1").kendoMenu({
        orientation: "vertical",
        dataSource: [{ text: "Item1" }],
        select: function (e) {
            alert("Selected");
        }
    });
    // code which will be executed once the menu is created.
});
```